# How to build Android kernel to use DS-5 streamline?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, ds-5, streamline

I am tying to use ARM DS5 Streamline for Android.

---

To use Streamline with your Android target, you must build the Gator driver, gator.ko and place it in the same directory as the Gator daemon, gatord, on the target file system. Transfer the gator driver module sources from your host to the target. They are located on your host here:

installdir/arm/gator/src/gator-driver.tar.gz

Assuming that you have unzipped the file and that you have all of the required tools for building kernel modules, enter the following command on your target to create the gator.ko module:

make -C kernel_build_dir M=`pwd` ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=<...> modules

---

I got this from ARM website. They say "target", are they meaning Android devices? Do I go through these steps on Android devices? Also what do they mean by kernel_build_dir? I know I could find kernel dir for my desktop linux machine. But I don't think I should pass my desktop machine's kernel directory as the parameter.

Comment: I've never read a guide so badly done. I also would like to try to use Stramline. Did you manage to get it working, or it's pretty useless tool. I'm interested in instruction level profiler, does Streamline do it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**target** is the device on which you are going to use Android. **host** is the machine on which you are compiling this driver/Android.

No, you have to compile kernel with drivers on your host machine and then upload it to your target device.

Kernel build directory is the directory that contains Linux kernel source codes. You will probably have to use some specific kernel version to be sure you are able to successfully compile your drivers, but your kernel would be okay too. Just read the how-to.

I hope, I have answered all your questions.